# How to retrieve taskbar alignment settings (left or center)

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, windows-11

Does the Windows API offer any function to retrieve the setting for `Taskbar behaviours` -> `Taskbar alignment` `[left]` / `[center]` , set in Personalisation settings?

[image: Windows Personalisation Settings]

Comment: It might be in the registry somewhere, but Microsoft don't tend to expose system settings like this via API any more (and haven't done for quite some time).

Comment: @JonathanPotter Hi Johnathan, thank you for answering. I am assuming [this]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 won't let me access the property either? I am going to take a look at the registry now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
With `winreg` in python

1. `ConnectRegistry`, then
2. `OpenKey` with Flag `KEY_READ`, then
3. `QueryValueEx` with two arguments: the var you set at OpenKey and second argument the name of the key you want to retrieve, in my case "`TaskbarAl`"

`TaskbarAl` values
0 = left
1 = center

Thanks to @Jonathan Potter to pointing me in the direction of registry.

Comment: When submitting a solution that's based on undocumented implementation details make sure to spell that out explicitly. Stack Overflow is used by professionals that may have different requirements than "enthusiasts".